# Extracting single argument type of optional function from another interface

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the following interface:

```ts
  export interface Props {
    requiredProp: string;
    optionalFunction?: (
      name: string;
      kind: 'animal' | 'human';
    ) => void;
  }
```

And I want to extract the type of "kind" argument of optionalFunction, so it would look like this:

`type Kind = 'animal' | 'human';`

I was trying to start with `Parameters<Props['optionalFunction']>`, but I get the following error:
`Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.`, because the function is optional

How could I achieve that?

Comment: You can use `Parameters<NonNull<Props['optionalFunction']>>`, or `Exclude<…, undefined>` to get rid of the optionality issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the type utility [`NonNullable<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) to help you. It:

> Constructs a type by excluding `null` and `undefined` from `Type`.

Don't forget to [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) the second parameter (at index `1`):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgBSgjAGc4BvAKDjimAEcBXBOgE0OIC44SYpkA5gG5qcYjAQQkmADYAxRkmwSpAfm4AKUTWkBbYN178kAgDTa4Aa2StuAIkxIEu2XbgAfOHYAWjF0jtzGgBKOABeAD44ADcIBFYRAF9KShgATzA8AGkbcIJMKEx9VCgSAB4AOSkKxhkZTAAjGWAyjlIAbTtxSWl5RWUeuwBdCIj2gEYhkRo4AHpZgD1VSiA)

```ts
export interface Props {
  requiredProp: string;
  optionalFunction?: (
    name: string,
    kind: "animal" | "human",
  ) => void;
}

type Kind = Parameters<NonNullable<Props["optionalFunction"]>>[1];
   //^? type Kind = "animal" | "human"
```